# SQL/PLSQL for mac operating system 10.13

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm a newer Oracle developer student. Can some one help me about any program for SQL Developer ? Can I install it on  iMacOS? I wantto really learn these languages (SQL/PLSQL  ) but iIdid not any idea if apps like toad can run on Mac many apps is expensive but which the best for learning and development

Comment: If you are asking specifically about Oracle/PLSQL, please do not tag unrelated products like MySql or SQL-Server.

Comment: Yes you can run SQL Developer on Mac. Installing Oracle is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a SQL client is simple.  Just download [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Getting a database is a different story. Don't even try to install Oracle on a Mac.  I'm an Oracle database administrator with years of experience and that idea scares me.  When I need an Oracle database locally I use [sath89/oracle-12c](https://store.docker.com/community/images/sath89/oracle-12c) on [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

I recommend that you read the [Oracle developer license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) carefully before downloading anything.  Oracle is commercial software and you need to be especially careful if you're not paying.

Answer (score 0):

If student and school has agreement with Jetbrains then DataGrip is really good. Sql Developer is also decent and has a MAC installer available.